# Docusign RESTful URL is not stable

Tags: api, rest, tabs, docusignapi

For some unknown reason, when I used the same URL that had worked yesterday, it won't work again today. Still not sure what is the reason.

The URL I used yesterday was (I did see tab content yesterday):

```
curl -silent https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/0000000/envelopes/aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/recipients/tabs?include_tabs=true
```

Today, the above URL will not work any more (I won't be able to see tab content) unless I change the URL to:

```
curl -silent https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/0000000/envelopes/aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/recipients/1/tabs
```

Strange. Not sure what is changed at server.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a different user account to login, then the first URL started to work. It could be somewhere there is a setting to control restful API behavior for each user account. But I am not aware where it is.